# How do I redirect both stderr and stout to multiple locations?

Tags: c, unix, redirect, stderr, tee

I need to execute a command in a bash script (on freebsd6), and I need to have both the stderr and stdout of the command sent to the console, a log file, AND to a bash variable.

So, without any redirection, what I want is:

```
result=`./command | tee output.log`
```

If I run this as-is, only stderr makes it to the console, and only stdout makes it to both the output.log file and the $result variable. I understand why that is, but many attempts at different redirections have failed to send both streams to all three locations.

How do I send both stderr and stdout to all three locations?

Answer (score 5):

```
result=`./command 2>&1 | tee output.log | tee /dev/tty`
```

[edit]

As n.m. points out in a comment, `tee` accepts multiple arguments:

```
result=`./command 2>&1 | tee output.log /dev/tty`
```

[second edit]

Borrowing an idea from Chris in the comments, you can also do this to send the output to stderr:

```
result=`./command 2>&1 | tee /tmp/foo.log >(cat 1>&2)`
```

To do exactly what you want, the best I have found is this:

```
exec 3>&1 ; result=`./command 2>&1 | tee /tmp/foo.log >(cat 1>&3)` ; exec 1>&3
```

(The whole problem here is that the backticks redirect stdout before anything inside gets to execute.  So this line saves and restores the old stdout as descriptor 3, which may or may not be a good idea...)

Comment: tee takes any number of arguments, as in `... | tee output.log /dev/tty`

Comment: One issue with this approach - if I want to redirect the output my parent bash script to another file, the output will not get redirected there.

Comment: you could use `/dev/fd/2` instead of `/dev/tty` on systems that support it, but this will send ALL the output to stderr (as well as to the log file and `$result`) which may not be what you want either.